# Get instantiated variable name inside class definition

Tags: python

In the `__init__` function of a class, I want to create a member variable `id`, which is equal to the string of the variable getting instantiated.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = f'{self=}'.split('=')[0] # doesn't do what I want...

        
foo = Bar()
print(foo.id) # I want this to print 'foo', but it prints 'self'

# this works, but I want to hide the code inside the class definition
foo.id = f'{foo=}'.split('=')[0]
print(foo.id)
```

Any suggestions how to make this work, if it is even possible?

Comment: First, `id` is a reserved keyword, you should not override it as a class member. Second, there is no way to know what variable a new `Bar()` will eventually be assigned to, if ever (that happens after the creation of `Bar`, and in a different context).

Comment: Which python version are you using? That f string syntax is incorrect.

Comment: No `id` is not a reserved keyword. @PierreD

Comment: `id` is a built-in function. Not a reserved keyword. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id

Comment: @PierreD well, it is *not* a reserved keyword, that is why you can use it as a variable/identifier

Comment: In any case, this is a *really* bad idea. In any case, the object has no idea what variable it is being assigned to, and it *shouldn't matter*. Variables aren't data, they are for the *person reading and writing the source code*.

Comment: @avio8: you're right & I stand corrected. It is indeed not a keyword but a builtin (many refs e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350862/758174)). It is still a very bad idea to use it as a class member.

Comment: the fact remains, naming aside, that there is no (clean) way of knowing what a new instance of the class will be assigned to, if anything. Sure, you could inspect the stack and do fancy things, but they are almost guaranteed to break at some point. In Python, if something looks really hard to do, there is probably a reason...

Comment: `foo.id` is `"self"`. Can you post what you'd like it to be? Is it just `"id"`?

Comment: Although you shouldn't use "id" as a variable name in the global namespace, it is perfectly fine to use it in other namespaces like class instances. Some syntax highlighters may color it funny, but that's really about all that'll happen.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? I cannot think of any case where this is useful.

Comment: I don't know why you need to do this. But if you provide a proper description of what is the main problem, we may help you to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, there is no (clean) way to know during the instantiation of `Bar()` what variable it will be assigned to (if at all).  Also, such a class could be assigned to another variable later on, then what?

However, after creation, there is a way to identify which variables contain a `Bar` instance:

```
bar_vars = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, Bar)}
```

You may even chose to change (mutate) some field in each `Bar` based on what's discovered in `locals()`, but that is *very* fragile and should be discouraged. For example:

```
for k, v in locals().items():
    if isinstance(v, Bar): v.name = k
```

That isn't robust at all: all copies of a given `Bar` instance will end up getting their name overwritten, and only the last one will win. For example:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

foo = Bar()
foo2 = foo

for k, v in locals().items():
    if isinstance(v, Bar):
        v.name = k

foo.name
# --> 'foo2'
```

A cleaner way is to provide an identifying name during init. It is a bit more verbose, but at least it won't surprise you at the least appropriate time, and you'll always know exactly what's happening:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign some value to self.id. That's the whole point of using **init**. To initialize when an object of that class is created. So this won't work.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.id = f'{self=}'.split('=')[0] # doesn't do what I want...
```

But this will

```
def __init__(self):
    self.id = 'foo'
```